# How to connect to ethernet while installing arch linux?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, system-installation, ethernet

I am trying to install arch-linux on my thinkpad following the [installation wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide). I plugged in the ethernet cable, and the `ip link command` will show:

```
enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtg 1500 disc state UP mode DEFAULT group default glen 1000
  link/ether f0:76:1c:ae:71:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I tried to `systemctl start dhcpcd@enp8s0.service` and got error:

```
Job for dhcpcd@enp8s0.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
```

Result for `systemctl status dhcpcd@enp8s0.service`:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system dhcpcd@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: protocol) since ...
```

It appears that the protocol our university network used is "EAP-PEAP", where can I indicate it in config file?

Also tried the default template for netctl copied from `/etc/netctl/example`, which also gives errors, and the `status "netctl@ethernet\\x2ddhcp.service"` command shows similarly:

```
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ...
```

I tried the `journalctl -xe` command also, but it is kind of hard to read from the result, is there any keyword I should grep?

I am trying to connect to our university network, which usually ask for my username and password. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Welcome to UL.SE. You should take a look at the [help] to get a feel for how SE works.

Comment: I have never seen a wired connection ask for authentication. Are you sure you are allowed to plug a personal laptop into the network and get an IP address? Usually it is wifi that requires authentication.

Comment: @strongbad I implemented 802.1X over ethernet for student usage. So yes, it is plausible. The AUP forbids anonymous use in many university networks

Comment: As a start, you can look into your issue with `systemctl status dhcpcd@enp8s0.service` and `journalctl -u dhcpcd@enp8s0.service` (querying the system manager and the logging facility, respectively). You can also type only `dhcpcd` and  then press <tab> in those commands, to let the shell complete the name of the unit for you (useful if some `dhcpcd...` exists with a name you would not expect). [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493818/edit) your question if you get meaningful information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the network infrastructure to test it ... A wired connection with EAP-PEAP authentication seems like a rare enough configuration that the generally helpful Arch wiki doesn't cover it. The Arch BBS, however does: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188783 The suggestion there is to use wpa_supplicant

> Create a netctl profile as following:
>
> ```
> Connection='ethernet'
> Interface=enp12s0
> Description="description"
> IP='dhcp'
> Auth8021X=yes
> WPAConfigFile=/etc/wpa_supplicant/dormitory.conf
> ```
>
> Create the /etc/wpa_supplicant/dormitory.conf:
>
> ```
> ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
> ap_scan=0
>
> network={
>     key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
>     eap=PEAP
>     pairwise=CCMP TKIP
>     phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
>     identity="mkristof"
>     password="pswd"
>     priority=2
> }
> ```

Comment: It does not work, it says control process failed with error.

Comment: @YilinLiu and you changed the identity and password and interface values to the appropriate values?

Comment: I did change the Interface Id and passed but not the ctrl_interface. Is there a special ctrl interface i need to know?

Comment: @YilinLiu no the interface enp12s0 should be enp8s0 for your device.

Comment: I did change that.